# php function oci_fetch_array is returning only one row

Tags: php, oracle

```
$stid = oci_parse('SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, DESIGNATION, DEPARTMENT, BRANCH FROM USERS');  
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS
                        | OCI_RETURN_LOBS)) != false) {

            $result[] = $row;
            }
```

`oci_fetch_array` is returning only one row while there are many rows in the table.

Comment: Would you please share the statement? ($stid)

Comment: $stid =  oci_parse('SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, DESIGNATION,
                              DEPARTMENT, BRANCH  FROM USERS');

Answer (score 1):

it seems, your problem is related to `|` before `OCI_RETURN_LOBS` part.

Make your statement as below :

> ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, `OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS + OCI_RETURN_LOBS`)) != false.

Comment: It's not related to the mix of '+' and '|'.  A quick test shows the mixed syntax working.